# How do I reset the format of a Form after saving and going to a new record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have form that adds records to a table.  I have some VBA code on the `AfterUpdate` event of a combobox that changes the visibility of some of the other form controls depending on the value chosen.

I also have a save button, which runs this code when clicked:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

End Sub
```

When I click the Save button, the controls that were made visible in the last record are still visible.  I want to "Reset" all controls to their default visibility, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a procedure for the form's `On Current` event.  As you navigate to a different record, you can reset controls' visibility to your default choices.  You can also set visibility conditionally ... so you might set visibility of a given control based on values of the current record.

Comment: I actually just called the _AfterUpdate event of the control in the form's _OnCurrent event.  Works like a charm.  Thank you @Hans